# Jquery - trying to call function when div dynamically created

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get this working so that when a **button is clicked**, a **div is created** and when `<div id="login-history">` is created, a **function is run** against the contents of that div.

**Here's what I want:**

1: Click on button and it loads login history thus creating a new div with the id Login History.
2: When "Login history" is loaded fully i want the function to run which will check if each row matches in Login History.

Here's what I've got so far but it's not doing it for some reason:

```js
//when accounts tab is clicked, run the checker function
$("#accountstab").on('click', function(){
    waitForElement("#loginhistory",checkerfunction());   
});

//function waitforElement that I got from here to wait on the element to load first as when you click accounts tab it may take 5-10 seconds to pull the login history

function waitForElement(elementPath, callBack){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
      if($(elementPath).length){
        callBack(elementPath, $(elementPath));
      }else{
        waitForElement(elementPath, callBack);
      }
    },500);
  }

function checkerfunction(){     
//variables of each Row in log history
var ip1 = $("#div.row.login-history").first();
var ip2 = $("#div.row.login-history").first().next();
var ip3 = $("#div.row.login-history").last().prev();
var ip4 = $("#div.row.login-history").last();
if ( $(ip1).text() == $(ip2).text() == $(ip3).text() == $(ip4).text()  ) {
//if they match, do nothing
}
else {
//add red banner alert if they don't match
    $("#accountstab").prepend("<div class='#alert warning'><span class='closebtn'>&times;</span><strong>Warning!</strong>Check the rows below for mismatch</div>");
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *invoking* the callback function instead of *passing* it. So change this:

```
waitForElement("#loginhistory",checkerfunction());
```

with:

```
waitForElement("#loginhistory",checkerfunction);
```

```js
//when accounts tab is clicked, run the checker function
$("#accountstab").on('click', function(){
    // Simulate load delay (for this snippet)
    setTimeout(function () { 
        $('<div>').attr('id', 'loginhistory').text('loaded').appendTo('body');
    }, 3000);
    waitForElement("#loginhistory", checkerfunction);   
});

function waitForElement(elementPath, callBack){
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if($(elementPath).length){
            console.log('found! callback');
            callBack(elementPath, $(elementPath));
        }else{
            console.log('not yet found...');
            waitForElement(elementPath, callBack);
        }
    }, 500);
}

function checkerfunction(){     
    console.log('callback called');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="accountstab">accountstab</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've changed it and now it will run if I paste it into the console but it won't run normally. Is there something wrong with the way it's waiting for the element?

When I paste it in the console it works as the element is visible when I paste but when it's waiting it doesn't actually do it.

Comment: You probably have some other code that is influencing the behaviour. I added a snippet to my answer that demonstrates that it works.