# styling visited links in a dynamic div using javascript and local storage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to remove an animation in the visited links inside a dynamic div (the div changes every second using jQuery), based on local storage and javascript, the problem is the animation comeback after the first update of the data (the div reinitialize with new data and the js code stop working after that).

The problem is here (after 5s the animation comeback to the stories) : https://www.fussball-liveticker.eu/hamburger-sv-live-stream-ticker-heute.

Screenshot : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0tTE.gif))

My js code :

```
function check_visited_links() {
var visited_links = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('visited_links')) || [];
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var that = links[i];
    that.onclick = function () {
        var clicked_url = this.href;
        if (visited_links.indexOf(clicked_url)==-1) {
            visited_links.push(clicked_url);
            localStorage.setItem('visited_links', JSON.stringify(visited_links));
        }
    }

    if (visited_links.indexOf(that.href)!== -1) { 
        that.className += ' visited';
    }
}
}

check_visited_links();
```

My css:

```
a.visited svg {
    animation: null;
  }
  .story svg {
    fill:none;
    stroke:rgb(218, 218, 218);
    stroke-width:3px;
    stroke-dasharray:1;
    stroke-dashoffset:0;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    animation:loading 3000ms ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

are you calling the function check_visited_links each time the html is changing?
I am seeing that you are calling the function for the first time i.e on load

Comment: how should i call it during the changes by the jquery ?

Comment: @Mons you can check this for calling a function from a dynamically generated html component https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691588/jquery-trying-to-call-function-when-div-dynamically-created

Comment: thank you for your help, i have no idea about how to use that example with my situation, i will be pleased if you can help with my situation !

Answer (score 0):

I tested and your localStorage was not written.

Maybe help:

```
let visitedStorageKey = 'visited';

let initVisitedLinks = () => {
    let visited = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(visitedStorageKey)) || [];

    visited.forEach((el) => {
        let currentLink = document.querySelector(`[href='${el}']`);

        if (currentLink) {
            currentLink.classList.add('visited');
        }
    })
}

let initVisitedListeners = () => {
    let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
    let visited = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(visitedStorageKey)) || [];

    for (let link of links) {
        link.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
            if (visited.indexOf(this.getAttribute('href')) == -1) visited.push(this.getAttribute('href'));
            this.classList.add('visited');
            localStorage.setItem(visitedStorageKey, JSON.stringify(visited));
        })
    }
}

initVisitedLinks();
initVisitedListeners();
```

Comment: thank you for your response, it does,  the local storage works fine, just after fetching new data and updating the div tag (the target div), the javascript stop checking the new update, even it includes the target class